# Resending email in SendCompleted Event

Tags: c#

I have a class called SchedulerService, and in it I have a SendMail function that's called when an email needs to be sent at a certain time. When I call the SendMail function, I pass in an object which holds the information for who to send the email to and who the email is from. Now, I've added a SendCompleted Handler so that I can possibly resend the email, in case something happens that causes it not to. I have this code that sends the mail:

```
    var recipients = EmailTo.Split(',').ToList();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailFrom))
        EmailFrom = recipients[0];

    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
      {
        message.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom);
        recipients.ForEach(a => message.To.Add(new MailAddress(a)));
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(LocationOfResults));
        message.Subject = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy} Results for task: {1}.", DateTime.Now, Description);
        message.Body = "Attached is the results file specified for the task: " + Description;
        smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.SendAsync(message, null);

                }
```

This is the event handler

```
    private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MailMessage mail = (MailMessage)e.UserState;
            using (mail)
            {
                 smtpClient.Send(mail);
            }
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Log(e.Error.ToString() + " in SendCompletedHandlerEvent", EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

    }
```

Problem is, I discovered that doing that doesn't work, as the To and From fields are empty, which then causes an error when sending the email. How should I go about reclaiming the To/From fields from the email that failed to send?

Comment: From where I see it I would say the problem is in your UserState property, since this is where you load the mail from, but you didn't provide enough code to see where the problem is exactly...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just added the code I used to send the email. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can't you just send it synchronously from a different thread?

Comment: So, originally I was trying to make a fix because of a DB lock up that caused the emails to not send. However, I'm not sure if that's an appropriate solution for the problem.

Comment: You are, unfortunately, doing it in a very wrong way.  Just for the illustration - what if it fails SECOND time?  Even if you fix the bugs complete mechanics of sending another mail from event that notifies you of mail-sending completion is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use asynchronius sending, then you should get rid of `using` block, it'll dispose you initialized `message` variable. Instead, you may call `Dispose()` from SendCompleted eventHandler or call Dispose just from the initialization method:

```
 /*...*/
 smtpClient.SendAsync(message, null);
 message.Dispose();
```

You may find this approach also on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) MSDN

Also, you should rewrite your initialization somehow, make it look like this:

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("somemail@gmail.com", "pass");
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.SendAsync(message, null);
            smtpClient.SendCompleted  += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
```

That is, I mean `SendAsync` with `Credentails` and other parameters needed to perform operation should be set first.

**UPD**
It'll solve problem of disposing the original `message` variable, cause that's why "To and From fields are empty".

About resending - provide please some more code or example of situation regardless how and where are you going to avoid message sending cancel and resending it.

Also what do you mean under the resending of cancelled message exactly? Is it right that you want to send cancelled message again?  As far as I understand it, you have no possibility to continue sending message which was cancelled using SendAsyncCancel() in your case.

In case of SendAsyncCancel executed, it still causes the SendCompleted event to be raised, but its arguments passed indicate that the operation was cancelled. So, you just can't escape it. You may want see [this page](http://blackwasp.co.uk/SendSmtpAsync_2.aspx), and also of course MSDN.

If you need so much sending message in case of some troubles that cancel it being sent, just send it again:

```
  /*your SendCompleted EventHandler*/
 if (e.Canceled)
  {
    //if you use using(message) {...} here, you'll get ObjectDisposedException again
   SmtpClient smtp;
    smtp = new SmtpClient();  
     smtp = GetClient(smtp);  //method of your smtpClient initialization
    MailMessage mess = new MailMessage();
    mess = GetMessage(mess, smtp);  //method of your mailMessage initialization

    try
    {
        //sending message again
        smtp.SendAsync(mess, null);

    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The email message was not sent. See the details:\n"+e.Message,
      "Error sendiing message")

     }
  }
```

I tested it using SendAsyncCancel method so I hope biggest part of cancelling reasons were taken in consideration.

Comment: Okay. However, I'm not sure if this helps with the original problem I am trying to solve of resending the email?

Comment: Please see the UPD section. If I've got you right, it  may help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing code that would be relevant in a synchronous scenario with code that's specific to an asynchronous one. So from an asynchronous point of view, here is a basic example of how you safely go about firstly sending the email:

```
var recipients = EmailTo.Split(',').ToList();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailFrom))
    EmailFrom = recipients[0];

MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
{
    From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom),
    Subject = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy} Results for task: {1}.", DateTime.Now, Description),
    Body = "Attached is the results file specified for the task: " + Description;
};
recipients.ForEach(a => message.To.Add(new MailAddress(a)));
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(LocationOfResults));
smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.SendAsync(message, message); // IMPORTANT - send message as UserState so we can access it in the callback
```

How handle the callback and dispose of the message:

```
MailMessage msg = (MailMessage)e.UserState;
if (e.Cancelled)
{
    // force synchronous send
    smptClient.Send(msg);
}
msg.Dispose(); // dispose of the message as we no longer need it
if (e.Error != null)
{
    Log(e.Error.ToString() + " in SendCompletedHandlerEvent", EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, you are doing it wrong.

One way of NOT doing it wrong is to create a loop similar to this:

- set 'mail sent successfully' flag to false
- set 'sending' flag to true
- try sending mail asynchronously as you are doing it
- in the event you are handling, check `e.Canceled` - if false, set 'main send successfully' flag to true.  Also set 'sending' flag to false (you completed the send process, right?)
- do something else for some time.  If nothing else is available, do `Application.DoEvents()` (yes it is wrong on so many levels, but let's keep it simple for now)
- check the 'sending' flag.  If still set, repeat previous step for some time.  Use counter to not get stuck forever.
- check the 'mail sent successfully' flag.  If it is unset, repeat.  Decrease some counter so you should not do it forever.

For good measure, put everything said above in secondary thread.  Instead of `DoEvents()` just `Sleep(50)` or something like that so you won't eat CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

The SendAsync methods second parameter takes a user token that can be read from e.UserState. So change your SendAsync code to:

```
    smtpClient.SendAsync(message, message);
```

And your code will work correctly.

Also in the SendComplete event, you can type-cast sender to get the actual SmtpClient.